# Mocking axios all / spread

Tags: jestjs, axios

I've got a very basic component that uses axios.all to make 3 calls to a jokes api and then stores the values in state.  I then map those values on the page.  Very basic stuff.

I'm trying to write a test that mocks the axios.all that I can pass some hard coded responses to.  I want to prove that the data binding is happening correctly after the call has resolved.

I'm having a very hard time doing this, and I was wondering if anyone had any insights.

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-river-s8ez2?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: R u able to test mock for all and spread. If yes, please provide me code sandbox link to see as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your test is that you are not mocking the `axios` methods. Simply calling it `axiosMock` when you import the library is not how it works.

You have to actually mock the methods you use:

```
describe("<TestScreen />", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Mock all the calls to axios.get, each one returning a response.
    axios.get = jest
      .fn()
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(RESPONSES[0])
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(RESPONSES[1])
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(RESPONSES[2]);

    // Spy on spread method so that we can wait for it to be called.
    jest.spyOn(axios, "spread");
  });

  test("placeholder", async () => {
    const { queryAllByTestId } = render(<App />);

    await waitFor(() => expect(axios.spread).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));

    const setups = queryAllByTestId("setup");
    const punchlines = queryAllByTestId("punchline");

    expect(setups.length).toBe(3);
    expect(punchlines.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to show me how to fix this.  I really appreciate it.